# Why Does my Data Initializer Not Produce the Expected Result?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have extended swift's Data type such that I can initialize an instance from an array of strings and subsequently recover those strings. I have two versions of the initializer; one of them works as expected, the other does not. I am here to ask for help with understanding what is going on with the nonworking version. Here is the extension (wherein I comment out one or the other of the initializers and then run the test code)

```
public extension Data {

    var encoding: String.Encoding { return .utf8 }

    // This version works
    public init(with: [String]) {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        with.forEach {
            data.append($0.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            data.append([0], length: 1)
        }
        self = data as Data
    }

    // This version does not work
    public init(with: [String]) {
        self.init()
        with.forEach {
            self.append($0.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            self.append(0)
        }
    }

    public func toStringArray() -> [String] {
        var decodedStrings = [String]()

        var stringTerminatorPositions = [Int]()

        var currentPosition = 0
        self.enumerateBytes() {
            buffer, count, stop in
            print("Enumeration count = \(count)")
            for i in 0 ..< count {
                if buffer[i] == 0 {
                    stringTerminatorPositions.append(currentPosition)
                }
                currentPosition += 1
            }
        }

        var stringStartPosition = 0
        for stringTerminatorPosition in stringTerminatorPositions {
            let encodedString = self.subdata(in: stringStartPosition ..< stringTerminatorPosition)
            if let decodedString =  String(data: encodedString, encoding: encoding) {
                decodedStrings.append(decodedString)
            }
            stringStartPosition = stringTerminatorPosition + 1
        }

        return decodedStrings
    }
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
    let strings = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    let encoded = Data(with: strings)
    let decoded = encoded.toStringArray()
    print("\(encoded as NSData) => \(decoded)")
```

Here is the output when using the working initializer:

```
Enumeration count = 19

<6f6e6500 74776f00 74687265 6500666f 757200> => ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Here is the output when using the nonworking initializer:

```
Enumeration count = 0

<6f6e6500 74776f00 74687265 6500666f 757200> => []
```

Please note the following:

1. In both cases the print out of the encoded strings is the same
2. The printing of the enumeration count in the toStringArray method reveals, however, that there is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your initialiser – the problem is with your use of `enumerateBytes`:

```
self.enumerateBytes() {
    buffer, count, stop in

    print("Enumeration count = \(count)")
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        if buffer[i] == 0 {
            stringTerminatorPositions.append(currentPosition)
        }
        currentPosition += 1
    }
}
```

What you're calling the `count` here is *not* the count – it's the *byte index* for the starting byte of the given region. The fact that it was giving you the length of the byte region for when a backing `NSData` store is used [is a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4028) (which will be fixed in the next Swift version).

To get the count for the byte region, you just want to say `buffer.count` – or given that `UnsafeBufferPointer` is a `Sequence`, you could also say:

```
var currentPosition = 0
self.enumerateBytes { buffer, byteIndex, stop in

    for byte in buffer {
        if byte == 0 {
            stringTerminatorPositions.append(currentPosition)
        }
        currentPosition += 1
    }
}
```

Or simpler still:

```
self.enumerateBytes { buffer, byteIndex, stop in

    for (offset, byte) in buffer.enumerated() where byte == 0 {
        stringTerminatorPositions.append(byteIndex + offset)
    }
}
```

Although *this* implementation currently won't work for `Data` instances backed by `NSData` until the bug is fixed, as `byteIndex` will incorrectly give you the length of the region.

But given you're calling `subdata(in:)` later in your implementation, which will copy the given bytes for each string into a new buffer – I don't really see the advantage of using `enumerateBytes` here. You could simplify your implementation by just using `withUnsafeBytes` in order to give you a contiguous view onto the data:

```
public func cStringsToArray(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) -> [String] {

    return withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<Int8>) in

        var strings = [String]()
        var previous = ptr

        for offset in 0 ..< count {

            let current = ptr + offset

            if current != previous && current.pointee == 0 {
                // if we cannot decode the string, append a unicode replacement character
                // feel free to handle this another way.
                strings.append(String(cString: previous, encoding: encoding) ?? "\u{FFFD}")
                previous = current + 1
            }
        }

        return strings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Swift bridges the constructor Data(with: strings) to NSData for the instantiation and this will not let you make changes after self has been initialized.

In your initializer that works, you make changes to a mutable instance and then assign it to self so that's why it works.

Even if you had declared encoded as var in your test, Swift would still have constructed the object first as an unmutable instance before assigning it to the variable.

You could work around this by assigning a mutable instance to self instead of using self.init():

```
// This version will now work
public init(with: [String]) 
{
    self = NSMutableData() as Data
    with.forEach 
    {
        self.append($0.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        self.append(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but because this is bridging to an ObjectiveC class, the methods are always available (the switch from NSData and NSMutableData happens at runtime) so the Swift compiler isn't always able to determine if the underlying object will be mutable or not.   This is also why assigning NSMutableData to self works (the Swift compiler really doesn't know what the bridge will do and has to assume that the method will be available).

Comment: Alain, Are you saying that Data is being bridged to NSData, NSData is not mutable, hence the append methods are silently failing?

Comment: Indeed. That's what's happening.

Comment: But, in both cases, the print statement reveals that the Data object has the correct bytes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OP's initialiser – the difference in behaviour between the two initialisers when using `enumerateBytes` is simply [a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4028).